# $K$ compact set $\subset A$ , open set of $\mathbb{C}$, implies that there exists $D$(smooth boundary) s.t. $K \subset D\subset \bar{D} \subset A$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I consider this situation: I have an open set $A\subset \mathbb{C}$ and a compact set $K\subset A$ and  I want to prove that there exists an open set $D$ such that $K \subset D\subset \bar{D} \subset A$ $\textbf{with piecewise smooth boundary}$.

In order to prove this fact should I use the theorem of decomposition of an open set ( there exists a sequence of open sets $\{U_i\}$ such that ${\overline U _i}$ is compact and ${\overline U _i} \subset {U_{i + 1}}$ and $U = \bigcup\limits_i {{U_i}}$.)?

How can I use it?

In this way I can prove that there is always a set $D$ s.t. $K \subset D\subset \bar{D} \subset A$ and $\partial D$ is piecewise linear, since I can construct every set $U_i$ with a piecewise linear boundary, am I right?

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps you should state in the title: $D$ with (piecewise) smooth boundary -- without this extra hypothesis the result is common fare. And the posters seem to miss it.

Comment: Surely a finite union of squares  has a piecewise-smooth boundary. That should do it. In fact, the boundary will be one (or several) polygons with right angles only. It seems that you can also smoothen the boundary, to get $D$ with fully smooth boundary. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @orangeskid Thanks!...I have that $A = \bigcup\limits_i {{U_i}}$, where $U_i$ are rectangles and this is a cover of $K$, so I can extract a finite subcover. And this finite subcover should be my $D$. Am I right?

Comment: Totally. Only make sure that the closures of the $U_i$'s stay inside your open subset that contains $K$.

Comment: @orangeskid Pelto's answer is alright too, finite union of balls will also have piecewise smooth boundary, similar to my solution with squares (I went for squares to make it piecewise linear and as you observed, you can make it all-smooth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it from scratch too. Let $(B_z)_{z\in K}$, $B_z=B(z,r_z)$ be a collection of open balls for each point of $K$ that fit in $A$. Then, let $(S_z)_{z\in K}$ be a collection of open squares centered at $z$ and side length $r_z$ $$S_z=(\Re z - \frac12{r_z},\Re z + \frac12r_z)\times(\Im z -\frac12r_z, \Im z + \frac12r_z).$$

Note that $z \in S_z \subset \overline{S_z} \subset B_z \subset A$. Now, because $K$ is compact and $(S_z)_{z\in K}$ is its cover, we can pick a finite subcover $(S_i)_{i=0,\ldots,n}$ and set $D=\bigcup_{i=0}^nS_i$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Good answer, +1. It feels easier to smoothen the boundary of a union of rectangles, rather than circles, but it could just be psychological. It's those raster images.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try something simpler.

$A$ is open, thus $F=\mathbb C\smallsetminus A$, closed, and as $K$ is compact, with $K\cap F=\varnothing$, then
$$
d=\mathrm{dist}(K,F)=\inf\big\{\lvert z-w\rvert : z\in F\,\&\,w\in K\big\}>0.
$$
Define
$$
D=\{z\in\mathbb C: \mathrm{dist}(K,z)<d/2\}.
$$
Then $D$ is open and
$$
K\subset D \subset\overline{D}\subset A.
$$

Comment: Well I personally don't think it is very obvious to the novice mathematician that $d(K,F)>0$. There is a good chance the poster has never proved this fact or seen it proved. I could have easily taken the Lebesgue Number Lemma as given and claimed my proof simpler.

Comment: Why your $D$ has piecewise smooth boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is an open cover of $K$, for each point $z \in K$ there is an open ball of radius $2r_z$ which is entirely contained in $A$. Hence for each point $z$ of $K$ the open ball  of radius $r_z$ is also contained entirely in $A$. We denote by $\mathscr{F}$ the family of open balls $\{B(z, r_z)\}_{z\in K}$. By the Heine-Borel property, a finite subfamily of $\mathscr{F}$ which we denote
\begin{equation}
B(z_1,r_1), \, B(z_2,r_2), \, \ldots, \,B(z_i,r_i)
\end{equation}
covers $K$. Let $\rho=\min \{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_i\}$. Notice that if $w \in K$, then $w$ is in one of the balls $B(z_j,r_j)$. Hence we have
\begin{equation}
B(z,\rho) \subset B(z_j,r_j+\rho) \subset B(z_j,2r_j) \, .
\end{equation}
The ball $B(z_j, 2r_j)$ was chosen so that it is completely contained in $A$. Since $w$ is an arbitrary point of $A$, this holds for all points of $K$. Since the set $\underset{z \in K}{\bigcup} B(z, \rho)$ is open, the result follows.

What is being used here is the Lebesgue Number Lemma.